# std::array vs C-Style array for contiguous memory

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

This is an experimentation for interest only...

I'm trying to make a container which holds a fixed number of bytes (e.g. header) and a dynamic block of data (e.g. body) all in one contiguous memory block. In traditional C programming I would have `char[0]` as the last instance variable and I would over allocate `sizeof(struct) + data_length`.

This works in C++ but I want something nicer. So my question is does a `std::array` start with a pointer or can it be used in the same way as a native C-style array?

Here's some example code...

```
struct pkg_base
{
    virtual std::size_t get_body_size() = 0;
    virtual void *get_body_ptr() = 0;
};

template<typename _T, std::size_t _N>
struct pkg
    : public pkg_base
{
    std::uint16_t a;
    std::uint16_t b;
    std::uint16_t c;

    std::array<_T, _N> body{};

    std::size_t get_body_size() override
    {
        return ( body.size() );
    }

    virtual void *get_body_ptr() override
    {
        return ( body.data() );
    }
};

void _test_package()
{
    auto vec = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<pkg_base>>{};
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<pkg<char, 1024>>());
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<pkg<float, 1024>>());
    vec.push_back( std::make_unique<pkg<std::string, 1024>>() );

    auto const size = vec.front()->get_body_size();
    auto const *ptr = static_cast<char *>( vec.front()->get_body_ptr() );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `std::array` "starting with a pointer"?

Comment: "This works in C++" - no, it doesn't Standard C++ does not allow zero-sized arrays.

Comment: I wouldn't define an `std::array` as a _"dynamic bloc of data"_...

Comment: *placement new* is the way to have a "variable sized class".

Comment: @oneiros as far as I can see you edited out the apostrophes in my numbers,  why is that? It's valid code.

Comment: @Treebeard because it is not interpreted fine by the SO color formatter, it showed the rest of the code in orange. It was just for better legibility

Comment: @oneiros ahh, OK. I'll bare that in mind next time, cheers

Comment: I wish you had climbed down the thread before makin any decisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reference, the technique you are referring to is called `flexible array member`, and unfortunately, it is not supported in C++ as either core feature or standard library function. I find this disappointing.

`std::array` is a dressed-up C-style array (with some members which allow it's using as an STL container, like iteration, sizing, type introspection, etc).

The only way I know to achieve a functionality which would be similar to flexible array member would be to create an `std::vector<char>`, with size set to the `sizeof(header) + <extra bytes for payload>`, and than `placement new` header in the `vector.data()`. You can wrap all this in a helper class to save yourself some typing for multiple scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

> So my question is does a std::array start with a pointer or can it be used in the same way as a native C-style array?

From [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

> This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array T[N] as its only non-static data member.

So there's no other data member in there, just the `T[N]` array you wanted.

You can trivially confirm this for yourself using `sizeof` or looking at the code.

As an aside, names beginning `_[A-Z]` are reserved for the implementation, so you probably shouldn't be calling your template type parameters `_T` and `_N`.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::array` doesn't contain any pointer to data somewhere else, a `std::array` directly holds the data internally, there's no anything dynamic in there.

It has been designed to provide semantics similar to a standard array but with some characteristics of standard STL containers.

It's an aggregate class which is mostly implemented as

```
namespace std
{
  template<typename T, size_t S>
  class array
  {
    T __elems_[S];
  }
}
```

You have `array.data()` which already returns a C array so I don't get your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest type erasure as a general solution to your problem. In modern C++ there is a tendency to stay away from direct manipulation of raw pointers, unless inevitable:

```
struct common_part{
    //declare common data and ctor
protected:
    virtual elem* end(){return begin()+size();};
    virtual elem *begin()=0 ;
    virtual ~common_part()=default;
    virtual std::size_t size()=0;
};

template<std::size_t N>
struct instance_type:
    common_part{
protected:
    void elem* begin() override{return arr;};
    void elem* end() override{return arr+N;};
    void std::size_t size() override{return N;};
private:
    elem arr[N];
};

std::unique_ptr<common_part> ptr {new instance_type<N>{}};
```

Comment: why would you want `virtual` members when you don't need polymorphism? templates are more than enough for this purpose.

Comment: for the sake of type erasure. otherwise, the pair{begin,end} must be declared as common data members and treated specially. runtime polymorphism is a more flexible, robust yet compact and economic approach. In case of code bloat, the data member for {begin,end} looks better, but in the end dtor shall be virtual, so that correct dtor is picked by the pointer upon disposal.